# Delete rows from sklearn dataset

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I need to drop rows that have a value of 0 in the column 'target'without using pandas. I need two classes instead of three

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.datasets import load_wine
wine=load_wine()
X, y = wine.data[:, 11:13], wine.target
wine
```

Comment: You posted the question twice. Also be careful to modify X and y in synchrony, so that values and labels will stay matched

Answer (score 1):

You can use advanced indexing and broadcasting:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.datasets import load_wine
from pprint import pprint
wine=load_wine()
X, y = wine.data[:, 11:13], wine.target
# remove all rows where target is 0
print(f"Shapes before: {X.shape}, {y.shape}")
X = X[y != 0]
y = y[y != 0]
print(f"Shapes after: {X.shape}, {y.shape}")
pprint(list(zip(X, y)))
```

The code `y != 0` creates an array that is `True` where `y != 0` and `False` otherwise. We then index using that array in order to only select items where the label is different from 0.

Here is a smaller and simplified example to understand this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([0, 0, 0, 3, 5, 6, 0, 0, 3, 0])
>>> non_zero_indices = (x != 0)
>>> non_zero_indices
array([False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False,  True,
       False])
>>> x[non_zero_indices]
array([3, 5, 6, 3])
```